# Cannot get click="{ myTabNavigator.selectedIndex=3}" to work

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, tabnavigator

I have a mx:TabNavigator with 5 tabs. As a secondary navigation option for the user there is a "Next" button on each tab that takes the user to the next tab. Each "Next" button uses click="{ myTabNavigator.selectedIndex=x}" set to move to the next tab where x is the tab number. All of them work except for the one on tab 2 which is supposed to take the user to tab 3. Nothing happens.

I can copy this button to tab 0 and it works fine taking the user to tab 3. It just will not work from tab 2.

I have tried moving myTabNavigator.selectedIndex=3; to an event handler and have confirmed that the click event is calling the event handler, but it doesn't work from there either.

I have cleaned the project, restarted Flash Builder and the browser and cleared the cache in the browser. Cannot get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

John

Comment: What's special about tab2, compared to the other tabs? (other than your issue)

Comment: The only thing on the tab that the others do not have are 2 mx:DateFields. All the pages have a couple of ComboBoxes and an assortment of TextAreas and labels. I have a change method but it does nothing if it goes to tab 2 and going to tab 3 I do not see that is doing anything with the selectedIndex. I don't think the change method is an issue since I can get to tab 3 from a tab other than 2.

Comment: Seems like there must be something special about tab 2, for there to be an issue. Try to compare the tabs a little more closely.

Comment: please post your code. for sure something is wrong in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I found that the tab 2 itself had click="{EditDetailsTabNavigator.selectedIndex=2}" in it. Took this out and the button works. Guess every time I clicked in the tab it would fire.

Not exactly sure how it got there, but I have found when pasting into a property in Design mode that occasionally the paste goes some place else in addition to where I have the cursor. I think that is how it might have gotten there.